# Angular. Aot. Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I have a [test project](https://github.com/WiseBird/Angular-Aot-Example) where I try to use AoT compilation.
With the [last commit](https://github.com/WiseBird/Angular-Aot-Example/commit/853949ac74f356c771a286a183a687413cd02919) I've added typescript's path mapping:

```js
"paths": {
  "home/*": ["./app/home/*"]
},
```

usage:

```ts
import {HomeComponent} from 'home/home.component';
```

jit compilation works fine, but when trying to use AoT:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.aot.js
```

I am getting next error:

`ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve home/home.component relative to /home/sergey/projects/aot_test/src/app/app.module.ts., resolving symbol AppModule in /home/sergey/projects/aot_test/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/sergey/projects/aot_test/src/app/app.module.ts`

PS: I use Angular version 4.1.3 because it's current version of our project. I tried to update all packages in [separate brunch](https://github.com/WiseBird/Angular-Aot-Example/tree/update_packages), but it didn't help, the error remained.

PSS: Before the last commit AoT compilation was working.

Comment: Can you post you appModule?

Comment: Provide some more related code

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat, see [here](https://github.com/WiseBird/Angular-Aot-Example/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: @ricky, what exactly do you mean? You can see all the code in the [repo](https://github.com/WiseBird/Angular-Aot-Example) and the last changes that broke AoT build in the [commit](https://github.com/WiseBird/Angular-Aot-Example/commit/853949ac74f356c771a286a183a687413cd02919).

Comment: [this file](https://github.com/WiseBird/Angular-Aot-Example/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts) line number 6 
change `import {HomeComponent} from 'home/home.component';` to `import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';`

Comment: @ricky, The point of the commit was to use typescript's mappings so I changed this line from relative path to absolute on purpose and I need to make AoT to work with it.

Comment: I am not sure but by seeing error message it looks like this is causing error. Did you try changing path and compiling using `aot`. Is it giving same error ?

Comment: @ricky, `by seeing error message it looks like this is causing error` yes, sure, before the last commit AoT was working fine. `Did you try changing path` if I revert it back to `./home/...` it will work of course, but I want to make it work with typescript mappings. So either AoT doesn't support them completely or I misconfigured something.

Comment: See this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17832) and [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17832#issuecomment-312741376)

Comment: @ricky, This issue is about problems with relative path, but it works OK for me. Also I do not use SystemJS, I use webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used incorrect path in tsconfig, it should be changed to:

```js
"paths": {
  "home/*": ["./src/app/home/*"]
},
```

JIT compilation worked because it ignores ts errors, unlike AoT.